# Enable a custom field placeholder to Woocommerce email subject

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, placeholder, email-notifications

In Woocommerce, I have added a custom field to the checkout page using the following code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'woo_add_conditional_checkout_fields' );
function woo_add_conditional_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
        $fields['billing']['billing_field_newfield'] = array(
            'label'       => __('New Field', 'woocommerce'),
            'placeholder' => _x('', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
            'required'    => true,
            'class'       => array('form-row-wide'),
            'clear'       => false
        );
    }
    return $fields;
}
```

Now, I would like to include the value that user enters in this field in the 'New Order' woocommerce email subject using `{billing_field_newfield}` custom placeholder.

However when I go to Woocommerce > Settings > Emails > New Order and put `{billing_field_newfield}` in the subject, I just get `{billing_field_newfield}` in the email and not its actual value.

How to add a custom dynamic placeholder to email subject in Woocommerce?